# OR clause in igraph selects

Tags: igraph

Is there any way to include an OR clause when selecting edges by attributes in igraph?

Something like:

```
seq = g.vs.select((Type_eq = 'Query') or (Product_eq = 'XBOX'))
```

Issuing:

```
seq = g.vs.select(Type_eq = 'Query', Product_eq = 'XBOX')
```

Performs an AND operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported yet; you can probably try standard Python set operations, though:

```
seq1 = set(v.index for v in g.vs.select(Type_eq='Query'))
seq2 = set(v.index for v in g.vs.select(Product_eq='XBOX'))
seq = g.vs[sorted(seq1 | seq2)]
```